# Maintain session between flask and android?

Tags: android, python, mysql, session, flask

I made a web app along with a flask backend which uses MySQL as the db and everything was working fine.

Now I decided to port it onto Android and use the same backend as it is with minor changes. Everything works as expected but somehow the session logic doesn't works anymore.

As soon as I validate login using the server, I set the session using a similar line like this -

```
session['phone'] = request.form['inputPhone']
```

Now this worked in a browser and any subsequent requests to other routes maintained this session. But on android this doesn't works whenever I query the server using *HttpUrlConnection*.

Do I need to pass the session variable each and every time while querying the server ?

Any help is appreciated and I can post my codes if anyone requires.

On a side note, I do have a separate session variable using *SharedPreferences* set on android but that is only for maintaining session after the app is closed and reopened.

Thank you